# rotation of map in slam_gmapping - how to de-rotate?

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a map produced by slam_gmapping. It looks pretty good. Straight edges, good loop closure, etc.
I started the mapping on a hardwood floor (and have tuned odom on a hardwood floor) but in the middle of mapping I have to pass a carpeted area where Z drifts until I get back to wood again. The drifting Z did not screw-up up the shape of the map at all, but it did cause the entire map to rotate (I was watching as the map was built and it didn't start to rotate until I got to the carpet). It means the wall that was supposed to lie along x axis is at 20 degrees or so.

Is there a way to correct this at the map level or will I need to insert a transform to rotate it back? Of course you already know the next question: how would that transform look?

Thanks in advance for help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236242/rotation-of-map-in-slam_gmapping---how-to-de-rotate?/) by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1850 on 2016-06-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-06-06**:
Why do you want to rotate the map at all? The localization and navigation algorithms don't really care about the map orientation.

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2016-06-06**:
I guess that is a fair question.  Fits easier (larger image with complete map) when map edges align with edges of screen and setting up the initial pose seems more complicated with an arbitrarily rotated map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're only worried about the aesthetics of the map, you can open the pgm file in an image editor (such as gimp) and rotate and crop the image to your liking.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2016-06-22**:
Thanks Hendrix. The time I opened the map the orientation was perfect so I didn't need to do anything.